# Resolving a Python object in global namespace by string look up

Tags: python

Let's say you want the object at the end of strings of object names: an example string would be `'first_class.second_class.third_class.id'`, and the list of strings all take the form `'X1object.X2object...XNobject.what_you_want_is_here_object'`.

In every case, you know that there is an active instance of the X1object, whatever its specific name. With the example string, the code has already called an instance of `first_class`. You can load `first_class` with `globals['first_class']`, and generically load `X1object` with `globals['X1object']`.

What you want is the object (usually a value) at then end of the string. So with the example string, you want the value of `id = first_class.second_class.third_class.id`. Is there an easy way to convert the string so that it fetches its end object?

Below is the code I created to handle this problem, but it seems like a brute force approach that fetches each attribute in turn until it finds the last one.

```
first_class = FirstClass()
first_class = go_do_something_wild_in_first_class(first_class)
...

attribute = 'first_class.second_class.third_class.id'
attribute_pieces = attribute.split('.')

fetch_attribute = lambda attribute, name: \
    attribute[name] if attribute == globals() else \
    getattr(attribute, name)

for name in attribute_pieces: # I changed the code from using an index to using a name
    if name == attribute_pieces[0]:
        attribute = fetch_attribute(globals(), name)
    else:
        attribute = fetch_attribute(attribute, name)

id = attribute
```

Comment: You want an actual instance of class X? And what is the actual goal? Because there might be an easier solution.

Comment: i have a list of strings like `'first_class.second_class.third_class.id'`. And I want to iterate over the list and return the final object as if I were writing `id = first_class.second_class.third_class.id`. The input is a string, and the output is the actual object which would be called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
def resolve_object(name):
    names = name.split('.')
    return reduce(getattr, names[1:], globals()[names[0]])
```

Here we simply look up `names[0]` as a global, then loop over the rest of the names to do a `getattr` for each one on the result so far.

Demo:

```
>>> class Foo(object): pass
... 
>>> first_class = Foo()
>>> first_class.second_class = Foo()
>>> first_class.second_class.third_class = Foo
>>> first_class.second_class.third_class.id = 'baz'
>>> resolve_object('first_class.second_class.third_class.id')
'baz'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Python library called zope.dottedname which does exactly what you want:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.dottedname

It resolves arbitrary strings to corresponding objects in Python namespace, including attributes of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [importlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html)

```
attribute = 'first_class.second_class.third_class.id'
attribute_pieces = attribute.split('.')

id = getattr(importlib.import_module('.'.join(attribute_pieces[:-1]), attribute_pieces[-1])
```